# Create a new cassandra cluster on Frankfurt region using DataStax Opscenter

Tags: amazon-web-services, cassandra, datastax, datastax-enterprise, opscenter

I want to create a new cassandra cluster using Datastax Opscenter(5.2.4) on AWS Frankfurt region (eu-central-1) and following the documentation here: http://docs.datastax.com/en/latest-opsc/opsc/online_help/opscCreateClusterCloud.html

When i click 'Create brand new cluster' only 'Local' option is available as provisioning type. 'Cloud' is missing.

I created another instance in Ireland(eu-west-1) to compare and found this:

An api call is made to '/rc/region/' that returns the name of the region where instance is running. Ireland instance returns 'EU (Ireland)' while on the other hand Frankfurt instance responds with 400 saying:

`{
"message": "'eu-central-1'",
"type": "KeyError"
}`

I know that datastax AMIs is not available in Frankfurt region, we had to built them ourselves. Maybe we did something wrong while building AMIs or there is a config we missed in the documentation. We would really appreciate if someone can point us in the right direction.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

OpsCenter developer here. Sadly, this isn't something that can't be hacked in the field. The region list is hard-coded and Frankfurt isn't available.

The workaround would be to launch your instances manually, and use "local" provisioning as if you were in a physical datacenter. Local provisioning does function in the cloud, and manual-launch + local-provisioning is roughly equivalent to cloud-provisioning (though admittedly less convenient).

EDIT: "can" -> "can't" That was not a helpful typo.

Comment: OpsCenter 6.0 has been released with a revamped provisioning feature called Lifecycle Manager. LCM is no longer tightly coupled to a particular AMI. You can provision to any supported operating system by launching instances using any public AMI.